# Django supported alternative to noSQL

Tags: django, nosql, bigdata

We need a reasonable insert and query speed over huge tables so I considered using some `noSQL` adapter with `Django`. Unfortunately:

- `Django` does not provide official support for `noSQL` databases.
- In our original schema some `Big Data` are relational to other `Big Data` making the data duplication unacceptable.
- Project deadlines are enemies of hot stuff like this.

So, as far I can see, `PostgreSQL` should be the way to go for this scenario, right?!

Please let me know any other detail that may be relevant to this question!

*Bonus to anyone that can point out some useful database techniques like database sharding...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a fork of django project that uses MongoDb as the backend.You can read about it [here](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) . The Code on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine).You give some heads up, MongoDB is a NOSQL db that does support sharding and replication. So i think this might something that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! It's seems a quite mature fork... Did you used the `Django` ORM with this?! There's differences in the ORM api?! (query filters, relatives objects and so on)

Comment: I think I've read enough about it to decided that's the way to go. Thanks again for the advice! I would be glad if you can point out some  draw backs or peculiarities of using this `Django` version in case that you already used it before.